# What portion of work is done alone by students of a class?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, puzzle, word-problem

The teacher said , the work can be done alone or in a group . So students can make group to do the work . $\frac{2}{3}$th portion of male students and $\frac{3}{5}$th portion of female students done the work in group . So what portion of work is done alone by students of a class ?

### My trying :

I have understood that this problem can be solved using vann diagram concept . But I cant understand how the concept of vann diagram should be applied here ?

Comment: Are you sure that is all? No information missing? Does it not say, for example, how many male and how many female students are in the class? Or the ratio thereof? Or is it to be assumed (without proof) that the ratio is 1:1?

Answer (score 1):

Let $b$ the proportion of boys in the class, so $1-b$ i the proportion of girls (this is where Venn diagram helps).

We have that:

$\frac{2}{3}b + \frac{3}{5}(1-b)$  is the opposite of the proportion you are looking for. Simplifying a bit:

$\frac{1}{15}b + \frac{9}{15}$

The proportion of students, not working in group is:

$1 - (\frac{1}{15}b + \frac{9}{15}) = \frac{6}{15} - \frac{1}{15}b$

Doing some further assumption like the proportion of boys and girls is the same, so $b=\frac{1}{2}$. We can say the the proportion of students working in group is:

$\frac{1}{15}\frac{1}{2} + \frac{9}{15}  = \frac{19}{30}$

And of course the proportion of students not working in group, supposing there is the same number of boys and girls,  would be $1-\frac{19}{30} = \frac{11}{30}$

Answer (score 1):

This question seems to be missing information, and thus has no solution without additional clarification. My advice what to do when facing questions such as this one:

- Try really hard to see if the missing information is there, just buried in the words. (In this problem, I don't believe it is.)
- Don't think it is your fault, that you "suck at maths" etc. Teachers are fallible like all humans, and information may well be genuinely missing.
- Convince yourself, by building examples where *you* supply the missing information, that the problem really is not solvable without this information.

For example, with 3 boys and 5 girls, you will have 1 boy and 2 girls working alone, which is 3/8 of the total. With 6 boys and 5 girls, you have 2 boys and 2 girls working alone, which is 4/11 of the total. Obviously, $3/8\ne 4/11$.

- Finally, throw the problem back to whoever gave it to you and ask for clarification. If they are reasonable, they will help; if not, it's again not your fault.